# Change the content (different languages) of React Components when clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I want to create a React Website where you can click on a button and change the language to German or English. I'm new to React and still learning.

I created a simple JSON that looks like this:

```
{
  "de": {
    "header": "Willkommen",
    "footer": "Auf Wiedersehen"
  },
  "eng": {
    "header": "Welcome",
    "footer": "Goodbye"
  }
}
```

I created a button that toggles its state when **onClick**. But I think state is the wrong way to do this if I want to access it everywhere.

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isOn: true};
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick() {
    if (this.state.isOn) {
      this.setState({isOn: false})
    } else {
      this.setState({isOn: true})
    }
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>DE/ENG{JSON.stringify(this.state.isOn)}</button>
    );
  }
}
```

And now I want to import the JSON data and put the right one in the components. This one down here isn't working. I don't know how to do it. Every component should get the German or English data when the button is clicked. I want to use it in many components. (It's working when I use const data = DATA.de for example but that won't change the content when I click the button.)

```
import DATA from './data.json';

class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const data = Button.state.isOn ? DATA.de : DATA.eng;
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onIsOnChange={this.buttonChange} />
        <span>{data.header}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React encourages you to "lift state", and this is a great opportunity to do so. I'd recommend you remove the state and `handleClick` method from the `Button` element (try using a [functional stateless component](https://hackernoon.com/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc)), and instead add the same state (on/off) to the `Main` element. When the button is clicked, simply make a call (using the onClick attribute) to `this.props.handleClick`. You'll need to give `handleClick` as a prop to the button, and in your `Main` element's `handleClick` method, set your state accordingly. You'll also need to give your `Button` component an `isOn` prop.

In `Main` your `data` const will then respond to `this.state.isOn`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to change your design a bit. Create a language change (call it 'onLanguaheChange' for example) method on Main component and pass it as a prop to you Button component,

```
<Button onClick={this.onLanguageChange}.../>
```

now, inside Button component, you can just call  `this.props.onClick(...)` and pass it the selected/required language. It will call the Main componemt method `onLanguageChange` with your parameter. Then you can change Main's state as desired, and pass it to what ever component you'd like.